# Automatically generate nested table of contents based on heading tags

Tags: php, dynamically-generated

Which one of you crafty programmers can show me an elegant php coded solution for automatically generating a nested table of contents based on heading tags on the page?

So I have a html document thus:

```
<h1> Animals </h1>

Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.

<h2> Mammals </h2>

Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.

<h3> Terrestrial Mammals </h3>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.

<h3> Marine Mammals </h3>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.

<h4> Whales </h4>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
```

More specifically, I want a linked table of contents in the form of a nested list of links to headings on the same page:

Table of Contents (automatically generated by PHP code)

1. Animals

   1. Mammals

      1. Terrestrial_Mammals
      2. Marine_Mammals

         1. Whales

Comment: Shouldn't Mammals be indented and starting with `1`?

Comment: oops, my bad ! I'll edit my question

Comment: How is the HTML content generated? Is that static user input? If it’s data (DB, array) with titles being put into the `h`-tags it’ll be a lot easier then if you only have one string with all that content; then you’ll first have to analyse the string for `h`-tags.

Comment: the HTML is in a database, it gets in one string variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this method, by Alex Freeman (http://www.10stripe.com/articles/automatically-generate-table-of-contents-php.php):

```
    preg_match_all('#<h[4-6]*[^>]*>.*?<\/h[4-6]>#',$html_string,$resultats);

    //reformat the results to be more usable
    $toc = implode("\n",$resultats[0]);
    $toc = str_replace('<a name="','<a href="#',$toc);
    $toc = str_replace('</a>','',$toc);
    $toc = preg_replace('#<h([4-6])>#','<li class="toc$1">',$toc);
    $toc = preg_replace('#<\/h[4-6]>#','</a></li>',$toc);

    //plug the results into appropriate HTML tags
    $toc = '<div id="toc"> 
    <p id="toc-header">Table des matières</p>
    <hr />
    <ul>
    '.$toc.'
    </ul>
    </div><br /><br />';

    return $toc;
```

In the HTML, the headers have to be written as:

```
<h2><a name="target"></a>Text</h2>
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't find it elegant, but might help in getting general idea how to create one ;)

It uses [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to find and manipulate elements in original html

```
$htmlcode = <<< EOHTML
<h1> Animals </h1>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
<h2> Mammals </h2>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
<h3> Terrestrial Mammals </h3>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
<h3> Marine Mammals </h3>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
<h4> Whales </h4>
Some content goes here.
Some content goes here.
EOHTML;
// simpehtmldom or other dom manipulating library
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = str_get_html($htmlcode);

$toc = '';
$last_level = 0;

foreach($html->find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6') as $h){
    $innerTEXT = trim($h->innertext);
    $id =  str_replace(' ','_',$innerTEXT);
    $h->id= $id; // add id attribute so we can jump to this element
    $level = intval($h->tag[1]);

    if($level > $last_level)
        $toc .= "<ol>";
    else{
        $toc .= str_repeat('</li></ol>', $last_level - $level);
        $toc .= '</li>';
    }

    $toc .= "<li><a href='#{$id}'>{$innerTEXT}</a>";

    $last_level = $level;
}

$toc .= str_repeat('</li></ol>', $last_level);
$html_with_toc = $toc . "<hr>" . $html->save();
```

Comment: This post is ancient,... but helpful! When I use this script, I notice that the OL and LI tags do not get closed at the end. I needed to add `  $toc .= str_repeat('</li></ol>', $level );` at the end, outside of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

Here’s an example using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);

// create document fragment
$frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
// create initial list
$frag->appendChild($doc->createElement('ol'));
$head = &$frag->firstChild;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$last = 1;

// get all H1, H2, …, H6 elements
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6]') as $headline) {
    // get level of current headline
    sscanf($headline->tagName, 'h%u', $curr);

    // move head reference if necessary
    if ($curr < $last) {
        // move upwards
        for ($i=$curr; $i<$last; $i++) {
            $head = &$head->parentNode->parentNode;
        }
    } else if ($curr > $last && $head->lastChild) {
        // move downwards and create new lists
        for ($i=$last; $i<$curr; $i++) {
            $head->lastChild->appendChild($doc->createElement('ol'));
            $head = &$head->lastChild->lastChild;
        }
    }
    $last = $curr;

    // add list item
    $li = $doc->createElement('li');
    $head->appendChild($li);
    $a = $doc->createElement('a', $headline->textContent);
    $head->lastChild->appendChild($a);

    // build ID
    $levels = array();
    $tmp = &$head;
    // walk subtree up to fragment root node of this subtree
    while (!is_null($tmp) && $tmp != $frag) {
        $levels[] = $tmp->childNodes->length;
        $tmp = &$tmp->parentNode->parentNode;
    }
    $id = 'sect'.implode('.', array_reverse($levels));
    // set destination
    $a->setAttribute('href', '#'.$id);
    // add anchor to headline
    $a = $doc->createElement('a');
    $a->setAttribute('name', $id);
    $a->setAttribute('id', $id);
    $headline->insertBefore($a, $headline->firstChild);
}

// append fragment to document
$doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild($frag);

// echo markup
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I tried this. for the moment it throws a fatalerror on $frag->appendChild

Comment: this code works only if you do not have a gap in your hierarchy like a `h1`followed by a `h3`.

Answer (score 5):

Combined some of the above to make a nested index of the headings. This function also inserts links into html itself so it can be linked. Pure php no library needed.

```
   function generateIndex($html)
{
    preg_match_all('/<h([1-6])*[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>/',$html,$matches);

    $index = "<ul>";
    $prev = 2;

    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $match){

        $curr = $matches[1][$i];
        $text = strip_tags($matches[2][$i]);
        $slug = strtolower(str_replace("--","-",preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '-', $text)));
        $anchor = '<a name="'.$slug.'">'.$text.'</a>';
        $html = str_replace($text,$anchor,$html);

        $prev <= $curr ?: $index .= str_repeat('</ul>',($prev - $curr));
        $prev >= $curr ?: $index .= "<ul>";

        $index .= '<li><a href="#'.$slug.'">'.$text.'</a></li>';

        $prev = $curr;
    }

    $index .= "</ul>";

    return ["html"=>$html,"index"=>$index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [TOC class](https://www.pakjiddat.pk/articles/view/259/generating-table-of-contents). It allows generating table of contents from nested headings. h1 tag can be followed by any lower level h tag. The class uses recursion to extract the headings from article text

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using SimpleHTMLDom :

```
public function getSummary($body) 
{
    $dom  = new Htmldom($body);
    $summ = "<ul>";
    $prev = 2;

    foreach($dom->find("h2,h3,h4") as $x => $htag) 
    {
        $curr = intval(substr($htag->tag, -1));

        $prev <= $curr ?: $summ .= "</ul>";
        $prev >= $curr ?: $summ .= "<ul>";

        $summ .= "<li>$htag->plaintext</li>";

        $prev = $curr;
    }

    $summ .= "</ul>";

    return $summ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very simple library for this [caseyamcl/toc](https://github.com/caseyamcl/toc)

```
$html='<h1>Title</h1>text<h2>...<h2>...';
$tocGenerator = new TOC\TocGenerator();
$toc = $tocGenerator->getHtmlMenu($html);
echo $htmlOut;
```

Bonus: If you want, he can fix the header without tag id by insert this code before.

```
$tocGenerator = new TOC\TocGenerator();
$html  = $markupFixer->fix($html);
```